# Как поставить mutex на файл Python?

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, mutex

Есть простенькая функция ведения лога в журнал.

```
def add_operation_in_journal(opeartion,clientAddress):
    mutex = threading.Lock()
    date=datetime.datetime.now()
    date = str(date)
    clientAddress = str(clientAddress)
    f.acquire()
    f = open('journal.txt', 'a')
    f.write(opeartion + "=====" + clientAddress + "=====" + date + '\n')
    f.close()
    mutex.release()
```

Как я могу проверить правильно ли я использую mutex для блокирования файла от других потоков на уровне ОС ?

Comment: Вообще-то, для блокирования файла на уровне ОС используют вызов [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) (и ряд аналогичных). Наверняка в питоне интерфейс с ними тоже реализован.

Comment: Даа, но к сожалению, задача состоит  в контроле доступа к файлу именно с помощью mutex, например с помощью pywin32

Comment: mutex это средство синхронизации для потоков (threads) одного процесса.  Другие программы, исполняющиеся параллельно с вашей, ничего о ваших mutex-ах не знают и поэтому использовать их для блокировки доступа к файлу не могут. Однако, в pywin32 есть [flock style](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/Windows_NT_Files_.2d.2d_Locking.html) блокировка файлов